# How to save the data to SQL table by using jQuery popup modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to store data collected from a modal into a sql server table.

HTML and JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,

            title: "LogIn",
            width: 378.84,
            height: 205.84,
            top: 157,
            left: 333
        });
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });

    });
</script>



<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Login"/>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" align="center">
    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="UserName"></asp:Label> &nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPassword2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Btnlogin" runat="server" Text="LogIn" OnClick="Btnlogin_Click" style="background-color: #33CC33"/>&nbsp;

</div>
```

Comment: As i understand you are using Asp.NET buttons in your project and even have defined  `OnClick="Btnlogin_Click"` click asp.net handler to login button. I think at this point you have two solutions: first is to create some rest service, to which you will post your data via ajax. The rest application then will write your data to sql server table. The second is to use `Btnlogin_Click` handler and write some c# asp.Net code which will write your data to SQL server table. Have you done research in any of these directions?